# git branching and basic process for a new dev

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm setting up a new dev pc and when I cloned our project using the url from the azure devops site, I realized that I was on the master branch instead of the one where I work on. The only thing in master is the initial commit when the project was created. We do all our work on and do our pushes to the `dev` branch.

When cloning an existing repo, should you start with the branch you work on, or start with master and then checkout the other branch, followed with a pull? What's the "correct" way to get a new environment up in a similar situation? I just don't want to miss a step that I'm not aware of.

For branches, here's what I found:

`git branch` shows me just:

`* master`

`git branch -all`

```
    remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master 
    remotes/origin/dev
    remotes/origin/master
    remotes/origin/somefeature
```

and `git status` shows:
`your branch is up to date with origin/master`

I was thinking about deleting the repo and starting over and cloning the dev branch instead, but I'm not sure if that's what you should do. I'd like to know what someone with more git experience would do here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only a single remote repository:

When cloning a repo, the default branch is whatever HEAD is set to. Usually, this is `master`/`main` or whatever the 'default' branch is.

You can use `git checkout -b <local_branch_name> <remote_branch_name>` to create and switch to a local branch that starts at the head of the remote branch and also tracks that remote branch (aka pushing will push to that remote branch).

In your case, assuming that what you said is actually correct (all of your developers do all work on the same `dev` branch?), you can do `git checkout -b dev origin/dev` to create a local branch called 'dev' that tracks the remote `dev` branch

Comment: We do only have one repo. Does each clone create new folders on your local machine? It's confusing because my old machine has one project folder, all dev code, and if I run git branch (without -all) it shows *dev followed by master.  So I'm wondering how I would now get the same thing on my new pc? Meaning, a single folder and have it be all dev code and when I do git branch it shows *dev followed by master. I'd like to just be in the same state because everything works on the old machine. Pipelines too. Or does it not create new folders for each branch?

Comment: Assuming I understand you, cloning creates a new folder, and creating a new branch does not (This is a massive simplification of what is actually happening). A repo can be considered a collection of branches - to duplicate the state you describe in your comment on a new PC, you need to clone the repo (which by default sets you to the `master` branch), open the folder created by cloning the repo, and then run `git checkout -b dev origin/dev`. This will create a local branch called 'dev' which is the same as the remote `dev` branch.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But since I now have a folder structure  representing master since that's what I cloned, if I do checkout -b dev origin/dev, will it just replace all the files there now with what's in origin dev and just "hide" the master? I guess I'll just do it but i'm curious how it gets code from dev which is totally different than master, and maintains the same proj folders. Note-i'm from a non-distributed folder based source world.

Comment: jren - "to duplicate the state you describe in your comment on a new PC, you need to clone the repo"

That's what I initially did. I cloned the repo which defaults to master.

Comment: sorry, and why does it say remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master when I do git branch -a? It shows that in both old and new pc. What does that mean

Comment: Yes, if you checkout a new branch, all of the emptiness of master will be replaced by the contents of the new branch. If you see the hidden `.git` folder inside of your repo, all of the inactive (so anything besides `master` for you currently) branches are 'stored' (another massive simplification) in that `.git` folder.

Comment: I believe origin/HEAD is the 'default' starting point that you get when you clone a repo. `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` basically means that the default starting branch of the repo is the master branch.

Comment: Ah. So that explains why I got master branch. Last thing, I just read that switch -b creates a branch. Should I just be doing git checkout without the -b? Because we already have a dev branch, I just don't have it on my machine. Just curious, I don't want to create a new branch that's not in our repo. I just want to get the existing dev branch on my local machine. thx

Comment: You should include the `-b` when doing `git checkout -b ...`. What your question is actually asking is 'how do I create a new local branch based off of the remote dev branch?'. `git checkout -b dev origin/dev` will create and switch to a local branch called `dev` that tracks the remote branch `dev`. This means that when you push your changes, git will know that it should push the contents of your local `dev` branch to the remote `origin/dev` branch so that other people can see the changes that you have made.

Answer (score 0):

If I were an admin of your repo, I would [change the default branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/change-default-branch?view=azure-devops) in Azure Devops to `dev`. This way all fresh clones would initially have `dev` checked out instead of `master`. It doesn't really matter that much- to answer your question there isn't a *correct* way, but setting `dev` to the default saves everyone from having to checkout the `dev` branch (which is simply: `git switch dev`) before they begin working.

**Additional thought**: You mentioned the only commit on `master` is an initial commit. Do you intend to do anything else with that branch? If no, I would just delete `master` to avoid confusion. If you wish to keep it around, one common use for it would be for `master` to represent production code. So when you have hardened your `dev` branch, after you release it to production, merge `dev` into `master`. That way if you have to do a hotfix to production you could branch off of `master` instead of `dev` to work on the fix. Just make sure to merge `master` with the new hotfix in it back into `dev` when you're done. Note though, you could also just tag releases to production and avoid the `master` branch altogether. Then hotfixes would need to branch off of the latest tag instead of `master`. Entirely up to you...

Comment: Yes, master just has the first commit, but that might change to be exactly what you said- prod code. I really don't know. We run a pipeline and at some point we'll probably introduce main into it. Stupid question: if I do git checkout -b dev, will it create a whole new set of folders ? Or will it replace what's there, master, with dev? I've literarily never done this.  Also, if I did the clone of dev instead of master, would git -b show me *dev followed by master? Because my old pc displays that and all the code in there is dev and there are no other "master" folders or anything.

Comment: @MattoMK You don't clone a "branch", you clone a "repo", which contains all those branches. You can only have one branch checked out at a time in each copy of the repo. When you switch from one branch to another branch, your file system will change to match the file structure of the tip commit of that branch. When you list your branches with `git branch`, it will show you all your local copies of branches you have ever checked out (and haven't deleted yet). The `*` is next to the local branch that you currently have checked out.

Comment: @MattoMK it may help to realize that a commit is a snapshot of the file system at the time the commit is made. When you switch from one commit to another your file system will update to match the snapshot of that commit. Branches are just pointers to specific commits. I'd recommend spending some time reading some tutorials on Git to get a better feel for it. Also consider making some new throwaways repos of your own and play around with creating files, committing them, and switching branches to watch them disappear and reappear.

Comment: @MattoMK some additional notes about checkout. `git switch` is the newer syntax for `git checkout`. Some of the options are slightly different though. You don't need to add options if you are checking out a local branch that already exists, or if you are checking out a branch with the same name as a remote branch. So, `git switch dev` will checkout your local copy of `dev` if it exists, and if not, it will make a copy of `origin/dev` and call it `dev`. If you want to make a new branch with a different name, that's when you would use `git switch -c new-branch` (or `git checkout -b new-branch`).

Comment: I like the idea of experimenting with things that aren't important to get a feel, nothing worse than doing this under pressure. And switch sound more intuitive too. Now I have a new issue (unrelated). doing npm install to install all the packages, created changes in our package-lock json file. It changed the lockfileVersion from 1 to 2, and it added hundreds of new entries. I have no idea why it would do this and if it'll screw something up if/when I check it in.

Comment: @MattoMK you're on a brand new topic with npm. I'd suggest researching that and/or asking a new question about that. That being said, since I happen to know this, you usually want to check-in your package-lock.json file, and typically you would use `npm ci` instead of `npm install` when you're passively using the lock file. Running `npm install` intentionally re-writes the lock file when you know you need to update it.

Comment: Well, if that's the case I'm going to delete this local repo and start over and use npm ci. I've always used install and never had an issue. I don't know what passive means in this context, I just knew I needed to get the packages from the repo and get them running locally (I suspect that's what you mean by passive). The app runs, but with many changes and not knowing the impact on the dev, I can't check it in.

Comment: @MattoMK yeah- that's what I meant by passive. There are ways to reset your way back without re-cloning, but if it's not too time consuming you could just blow it away and reclone. That may be easier than figuring out which npm directories you have to delete too. Once you start committing your own branches and configuring your local repo certain ways, you'll probably wish to avoid re-cloning if possible. But for now, that's an easy fix.